# Simple TinyMce throws "o is not Constructor" and "property onload of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, angular-ui-tinymce

Following the tuts and seting up a TinyMce it throws me at Loading of the Site with Tinymce
`Uncaught TypeError: o is not a constructor`
Changing to other sites throws
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null`
Redirecting to the Point where it Errors

```
function et() {
    var e = !0
      , n = this;
    this.debugEnabled = function(n) {
        return y(n) ? (e = n,
        this) : e
    }
    ,
    this.$get = ["$window", function(t) {
        function l(e) {
            return e instanceof Error && (e.stack ? e = e.message && e.stack.indexOf(e.message) === -1 ? "Error: " + e.message + "\n" + e.stack : e.stack : e.sourceURL && (e = e.message + "\n" + e.sourceURL + ":" + e.line)),
            e
        }
        function i(e) {
            var n = t.console || {}
              , i = n[e] || n.log || p
              , o = !1;
            try {
                o = !!i.apply
            } catch (e) {}
            return o ? function() {
                var e = [];
                return r(arguments, function(n) {
                    e.push(l(n))
                }),
                i.apply(n, e)// Errors here
            }
            : function(e, n) {
                i(e, null == n ? "" : n)
            }
        }
        return {
            log: i("log"),
            info: i("info"),
            warn: i("warn"),
            error: i("error"),
            debug: function() {
                var t = i("debug");
                return function() {
                    e && t.apply(n, arguments)
                }
            }()
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

The Setup

```
.html    
<td>
 <textarea ui-tinymce='tinymceOptionsRead' ng-model='originalText' ></textarea>
</td>
.js 
   class HtmlvalueComponent {
        constructor($scope) {
          this.$scope.tinymceOptionsRead = {
            menubar: false,
            theme: 'modern',
            plugins: '',
            toolbar: false,
            readonly: true,
            statusbar: false,
            height: 170,
          };
        }
```

Because there are no further Infos at the Error Log and Google doesnt give out Solutions I need help.

If I comment in the `.js` File the `tinymceOptionsRead` out and not setting it in the `.html` as `<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model='originalText' ></textarea>` it still throws both Errors.
If I comment only the TinyMce out
`<!--textarea ui-tinymce ng-model='originalText' ></textarea-->`
then the Errors Vanish, so there lies somewhere the Problem.
Everything else on the Site is working like Buttons,CRUD and so on
I have the lastest Versions installed:
TinyMce : 4.5.2
ui-TinyMce: 0.0.18
Angular: 1.5.8

Comment: Output of minifier in the original Files of `TinyMce` Package. The Error Directs in there .Just showed it so maybe it gives a hint where the Problem could be.

Comment: I've been playing around with tinymce myself today. I just want to mention that $scope should not be included in the constructor and so in this.tinymceOptions. It just doesn't look right. I have something similar but without $scope and I got to the error: Uncaught TypeError: Theme is not a constructor which is a TS error.

Comment: @luliaMihet Ive got it working. The Problem was that it worked under development and not under production. The Problem was that the needed Packages from TinyMCE were not Included at the moment by Bundling for Shipping out. Maybe its the same Problem you got?

Comment: nope, I was just trying to access the tinymceOptions and it didn't work, but that's because I was not adding them correctly to ui-tinymce in the textarea element.

Answer (score -1):

put jquery.min.js file under header Section of the page above any script. this trick worked for me.